# How to work on one SFML-C++ Project with different Visual Studio versions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sfml

I'm working on a C++ project that requires [SFML (free portable library)](https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) and some dependencies which I can copy onto a usb-stick/drive.

The issue is that I'm working with **Visual Studio 2019 at home** and very often **at uni/work with Visual Studio 2013**.

Whenever I try to run the project from one version on the other, exceptions and other errors are thrown around.
The only fix is creating a new project and annoyingly add each dependency & lib folder which I would absolutely 100% positively avoid at all cost...

How can I, aside from making two sepearte projects for each VS version, work on one project with different versions of Visual Studio?

I've tried using a portable codeblocks 17.02 copy but the IDE is not very pleasant to work with, especially since I own a Visual Studio Key and other students will review the code in Visual Studio as well.

This is just some simple window creation example:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    RenderWindow Window;
    Window.create(VideoMode(800, 800), "VS2013-VS2019Example");
    while (Window.isOpen()) {
        Event e;
        while (Window.pollEvent(e)) {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed) {
                Window.close();
            }
        }
        Window.clear();
        Window.display();
    }
}

I expected the program to create a new window, 800x800 with a title and no interception.
Starting the program will result in VS indicating that line 8, the line where window.create() is called, throws a Access violation reading location 0x000FFF exception at 0x0F15A5E3 (msvcp120.dll) in [project name].exe.
```

Comment: Maintaining a [cmake](https://cmake.org/) build system would be an easy way to generate build files suitable for different environments (assuming all the different environments actually support what your program needs - but if they don't, you're shit out of luck anyway).

Comment: Install Visual Studio 2013 at home as well and then choose the v120 platform toolset in your project's settings.

Comment: Although you said not to create separate folders, I created solution & project files for each version of VS (2008, 2010 and 2017).  The source files were in a common folder (single folder).  The temporary and library folders would be in a folder named after the VS version.  This worked out well for me.

Comment: Are you linking statically or dynamically? If you use dynamic linking you should be fine as long as you use the project built on 2013 with SFML built on 2013, same for 2019.

Comment: @super yes I link dynamically but it's still showing me the same error (msvcp120.dll) which indicates an issue with the different versions (120 = 2013, 140 = 2019). thomas matthews since so far it doesn't seem like anything could fix this issue, I will definitely consider your quick-fix, thanks!